# How to style columns in pandas without overlapping and deleting previous work

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing some styling to pandas columns where I want to highlight green or red values + or - 2*std of the corresponding column, but when I loop over to go to the next column, previous work is essentially deleted and only the last column shows any changes.

Function:

```
def color_outliers(value):

    if value <= (mean - (2*std)):
#     print(mean)
#     print(std)
        color = 'red'
    elif value >= (mean + (2*std)):
#     print(mean)
#     print(std)
        color = 'green'
    else:
        color = 'black'

    return 'color: %s' % color
```

Code:

```
comp_holder = []

titles = []
i = 0
for value in names:
    titles.append(names[i])
    i+=1

#Number of Articles and Days of search
num_days = len(page_list[0]['items']) - 2
num_arts = len(titles)

arts = 0
days = 0

# print(num_days)
# print(num_arts)

#Sets index of dataframe to be timestamps of articles
for days in range(num_days):
    comp_dict = {}
    comp_dict = {'timestamp(YYYYMMDD)' : int(int(page_list[0]['items'][days]['timestamp'])/100)}
    #Adds each article from current day in loop to dictionary for row append
    for arts in range(num_arts):
        comp_dict[titles[arts]] = page_list[arts]['items'][days]['views']
    comp_holder.append(comp_dict)

comp_df = pd.DataFrame(comp_holder)

arts = 0
days = 0

outliers = comp_df

for arts in range(num_arts):
    mean = comp_df[titles[arts]].mean()
    std = comp_df[titles[arts]].std()
    outliers = comp_df.style.applymap(color_outliers, subset = [titles[arts]])
```

Each time I go through this for loop, the 'outliers' styling data frame resets itself and only works on the current subset, but if I remove the subset, it uses one mean and std for the entire data frame. I have tried style.apply using axis=0 but i can't get it to work.

My data frame consists of 21 columns, the first being the timestamp and the next twenty being columns of ints based upon input files. I also have two lists indexed from 0 to 19 of means and std of each column.

Answer (score 0):

I would `apply` on the whole column instead of `applymap`. I'm not sure I can follow your code since I don't know how your data look like, but this is what I would do:

```
# sample data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100, [10,3]))      

# compute the statistics
stats = df.agg(['mean','std'])

# format function on columns
def color_outlier(col, thresh=2):
    # extract mean and std of the column
    mean, std = stats[col.name]

    return np.select((col<=mean-std*thresh, col>=mean+std*thresh),
                     ('color: red', 'color: green'),
                     'color: black')

# thresh changes for demonstration, remove when used
df.style.apply(color_outlier, thresh=0.5)
```

Output:

[image]